# SSRS if field value in list

Tags: sql, sorting, reporting-services, formatting

I've looked through a number of tutorials and asks, and haven't found a working solution to my problem.

Suppose my dataset has two columns: `sort_order` and `field_value`. `sort_order` is an integer and `field_value` is a numerical (10,2).

I want to format some rows as `#,#0` and others as `#,#0.00`.

Normally I would just do

`iif( fields!sort_order.value = 1 or fields!sort_order.value = 23 or .....`

unfortunately, the list is fairly long.

I'd like to do the equivalent of `if fields!sort_order.value in (1,2,21,63,78,...) then...)`

As recommended in another post, I tried the following (if sort in list, then just output a 0, else a 1. this is just to test the functionality of the IN operator):

```
=iif( fields!sort_order.Value IN split("1,2,3,4,5,6,8,10,11,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,26,30,31,33,34,36,37,38,41,42,44,45,46,49,50,52,53,54,57,58,59,62,63,64,67,68,70,71,75,76,77,80,81,82,92,98,99,113,115,116,120,122,123,127,130,134,136,137,143,144,146,147,148,149,154,155,156,157,162,163,164,165,170,171,172,173,183,184,185,186,192,193,194,195,201,202,203,204,210,211,212,213,263",","),0,1)
```

However, it doesn't look like the SSRS expression editor wants to accept the "IN" operator. Which is strange, because all the examples I've found that solve this problem use the IN operator.

Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `IndexOf` function:

```
=IIF(Array.IndexOf(split("1,2,3,4,...",","),fields!sort_order.Value)>-1,0,1)
```

Note all values must be inside quotations.

> Consider the recommendation of @Jakub, I recommend this solution if
>   your are feeding your report via SP and you can't touch it.

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: using the following results in #error in each cell:
=iif(array.IndexOf(split("1","2","3",","),fields!sort_order.Value)>-1,0,1)

Comment: this works:

=iif( (Array.indexOf(split("1,2,3,4,5,6,8,10,11,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,26,30,31,33,34,36,37,38,41,42,44,45,46,49,50,52,53,54,57,58,59,62,63,64,67,68,70,71,75,76,77,80,81,82,92,98,99,113,115,116,120,122,123,127,130,134,136,137,143,144,146,147,148,149,154,155,156,157,162,163,164,165,170,171,172,173,183,184,185,186,192,193,194,195,201,202,203,204,210,211,212,213,263",","),Fields!sort_order.Value.ToString())) > -1
,0
,1)

Comment: @user3654225, You are right, I was confused with join() function. At least you figured it out.